# Run C++ unmanaged console app (NOT a batch file) without a window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In order to avoid tangling with interop services (beyond my understanding) I use

```
spawnl(P_DETACH, MyPath, "MyProg.exe", 0);
```

to spawn a VS unmanaged C++ command line project. (It controls an astro-camera via the manufacturer's DLL).

I don't need and don't want a window (I talk to myprog.exe using named pipes from my main GUI program).

Suppressing the window from a GUI is trivial, but in order to avoid tangling with marshalling issues (beyond my comprehension) myprog.exe must be an *unmanaged* native C++ command line project, not a CLI project.

There is a huge literature on suppressing the window from a batch file or from python, and closing a window in a windows project is trivial, but that is all irrelevant here.

I spawn myprog.exe detached, but that is irrelevant. Closing the console handle executes ok but does not close the window.

Any thoughts on how to either never open the black onscreen DOS box, or how to close it without closing myprog.exe?

Comment: You should probably tag this Windows to be more clear.
Also, it sounds like you're more interested in a [service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Drop down a level and use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` in the [process creation flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` and `SW_HIDE` in the appropriate slots of [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?  (This is not an answer because I don't know if it will work.)

Comment: @Taywee I tagged it as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

void system_error(char *name) {
// Retrieve, format, and print out a message from the last errror.
// The `name' that's passed should be in the form of a present tense
// noun (phrase) such as "opening file".
//
    char *ptr = NULL;
    FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        0, GetLastError(), 0, (char *)&ptr, 1024, NULL);

    printf("\nError %s: %s\n", name, ptr);
    LocalFree(ptr);
}

PROCESS_INFORMATION p;

BOOL WINAPI die(DWORD reason) {
    TerminateProcess(p.hProcess, 1);
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    STARTUPINFO s;

    memset(&s, 0, sizeof s);
    s.cb = sizeof(s);

    if (!CreateProcess(argv[1], argv[2], NULL, NULL, TRUE,
        DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &s, &p))
    {
        system_error("Spawning program");
        return 1;
    }

    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(die, TRUE);

    WaitForSingleObject(p.hProcess, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly is the difference between `DETACHED_PROCESS` and `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`?

Comment: @Zack: To be honest, it's been long enough since I wrote this (or did anything very similar) that I don't remember.

Comment: [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) to the create process flags on MSDN should help.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Already looked -- their description doesn't make the difference particularly obvious (though my dim recollection is of the difference actually being fairly substantial).

Comment: It sounds to me (from reading MSDN) that `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` is the one you want. It actually skips creating the window for a console application, whereas `DETACHED_PROCESS` simply means that the new process does not inherit its parent's console window (and leaves open the possibility for it to create its own new console window). I could be totally wrong, though; I haven't tested my interpretation.

Comment: Thanks - will go away and learn about CreateProceess. Sorry about late response - been up all night photographing galaxies far away.

Comment: CREATE_NO_WINDOW worked superbly. Thanks again, especially for the example code.